# Why sfml gives me undefined reference to `_imp____acrt_iob_func' during linking

Tags: windows, cmake, mingw, sfml, undefined-reference

I was trying to create the example sfml window and compile with cmake but I received the following error: undefined reference to `_imp____acrt_iob_func'.

The only lib I'm using is sfml and I'm sure the problem is just on the link stage.

My CMakeLists file is the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26.3)

project(LES)

set(SFML_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/sfmlLib/lib/cmake/SFML/)
set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)
message("SFML_DIR = " ${SFML_DIR})
find_package(SFML REQUIRED COMPONENTS graphics window system)

include_directories(include)
include_directories(sfmlLib/include)

add_executable(Pong src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Pong sfml-graphics sfml-window sfml-system)
```

And the files are:
[File tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbRWv.png)

I'm using ninja to compilation and sfml for minGW 32bits

The error I receive is the following:

```
cmd.exe /C "cd . && W:\programming\MinGW\bin\c++.exe   CMakeFiles/Pong.dir/src/main.cpp.obj -o Pong.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libPong.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  "C:/Users/gcsil/OneDrive/├ürea de Trabalho/LeS/sfmlLib/lib/libsfml-graphics-s-d.a"  "C:/Users/gcsil/OneDrive/├ürea de Trabalho/LeS/sfmlLib/lib/libsfml-window-s-d.a"  "C:/Users/gcsil/OneDrive/├ürea de Trabalho/LeS/sfmlLib/lib/libsfml-system-s-d.a"  -lwinmm  -lgdi32  -lOpenGL32  "C:/Users/gcsil/OneDrive/├ürea de Trabalho/LeS/sfmlLib/lib/libfreetype.a"  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
C:/Users/gcsil/OneDrive/┴rea de Trabalho/LeS/sfmlLib/lib/libsfml-system-s-d.a(Err.cpp.obj): In function `sync':
D:/Programming/C++/Releases/_Sources/SFML/src/SFML/System/Err.cpp:87: undefined reference to `_imp____acrt_iob_func'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: "_Why sfml gives me undefined reference to `_imp____acrt_iob_func' during compilation_" isn't that a link error? Also, you probably don't need `include_directories(sfmlLib/include)` if you `target_link_libraries` and those SFML targets are set up correctly.

Comment: imp errors usuall pop up for me when the dll files for sfml have NOT been copied over to the build directory of the project